# sizeof return type in C

Tags: c

I understand sizeof tells the size of my object in terms of bytes. I wrote the following:

```
int a = 8; 
float size = sizeof a; 
printf("%f\n", size);
```

The output is 4.000000. Shouldn't it return .5? My understanding is that one byte contains 8 bits and in order to store the number 8 I need 4 bits.

Comment: The number of bits in a byte is not defined except to be more than seven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable `a` is an integer (`int`), and integers take 4 bytes (regardless of what value is stored in it).

Just because the specific value *could* be represented by fewer bits, it does not change the size of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

The size of an integer variable is fixed; it does not vary with the size of the value it holds.  In your case, you're using a 32-bit byte-addressable machine, so on that machine sizeof(int) is always 32 bits, aka 4 bytes.

Comment: What if it's a word-addressable only machine?

Comment: It makes a big difference because their bytes are 32bits and sizeof(int)==sizeof(short)==sizeof(char)==1

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying - I'll edit my answer to reflect that.  In any case, on such a machine the values returned by sizeof() would still not vary depending on what value was currently stored in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` operator operates on the data type, not on the variable *value*.

FYI, `sizeof(int)` is perfectly valid, too.

Answer (score 0):

The default int size on your system seems to be 32-bits.  It is regardless of the number of bits your number needs to be represented.

a link with some default variable sizes:

http://developer.mbed.org/handbook/C-Data-Types